# Fastlane could not find action or lane 'get_certificates'

Tags: ios, react-native, fastlane

I have a react-native app automatized in gitlab that was working well until yesterday that started showing this error:

```
Could not find action or lane 'get_certificates'. Check out the README for more details: https://github.com/fastlane/fastlane/tree/master/fastlane
+------+--------------------------+-------------+
|               fastlane summary                |
+------+--------------------------+-------------+
| Step | Action                   | Time (in s) |
+------+--------------------------+-------------+
| 1    | default_platform         | 0           |
| 2    | unlock_keychain          | 0           |
| 3    | increment_version_number | 0           |
| 4    | increment_build_number   | 0           |
+------+--------------------------+-------------+
```

this is the fastfile code:

```
require 'dotenv' 
Dotenv.load ".env"

default_platform(:ios)

platform :ios do

    desc "Push a new beta build to TestFlight"
    lane :build_develop do
        $appBundleIdentifierDev = $identifier
        $workspaceName = $workspace
        $ipaFilename = $filename
        $appleUsername = $username
        $url_repo = $repo

        unlock_keychain(
            path: "login.keychain-db",
            password: ENV['KEYCHAIN_PASS']
        )

        increment_version_number(
            version_number: ENV['APP_VERSION_NAME']
        )

        increment_build_number(
            build_number: ENV['APP_VERSION_CODE']
        )

        get_certificates(
            team_id: $teamid
        )

        gym(
            export_method: 'app-store',
            scheme: $scheme,
            configuration: $configuration,
            clean: true,
            include_bitcode: false,
            workspace: $workspaceName,
            output_name: $ipaFilename,
            xcargs: "ARCHIVE=YES",
            output_directory: "build",
            export_xcargs: "-allowProvisioningUpdates",
        )
    end
end
```

I didn't change any code in the last days and now it suddenly does not work. Any ideas of what is happening?

Answer (score 0):

Try to reinstall Fastlane:

- If you used [Homebrew](https://brew.sh) to install Fastlane:

  ```
    brew cask uninstall fastlane
    brew uninstall fastlane

    brew install fastlane
  ```
- If you used RubyGems to install Fastlane:

  ```
    sudo gem uninstall fastlane
    sudo gem install fastlane -NV
  ```

Comment: I tried that but the same error apears, also when I do `fastlane actions` the resulting list does not show `get_certificates`

Answer (score 0):

Consider replacing `get_certificates` with `cert` in your fastfile code.

`cert` is an alias for `get_certificates`. Maybe using the alias helps in your case